# Create an AutoCompleteTextField with javafx

Tags: javafx, autocomplete

I'm trying to set up an AutoCompleteTextField. I'm using Callback> versionCollection.

Here is my code :

```
Callback<AutoCompletionBinding.ISuggestionRequest,Collection<T>> versionCollection = null;
for (Object name : this.fixVersionModel.getFixVersions().keySet()) {
    versionCollection.add((String) name);
}
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(this.autoCompleteTextField, versionCollection)
```

I get a stupid error while my collection isn't initialized. Is there no better solution to make an AutoCompleteTextField? If no, could someone help me with my code ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please let us know what this 'stupid error' is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialised your `versionCollection` there so it's obviously going to throw an NPE

Comment: I've solved it by myself. My problem was that I didn't use a classic TextField but an autoCompleteTextField from controlFX.
Thank you